# Maximum modulus theorem on $\Bbb C_\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I wonder if the maximum modulus theorem holds in $\Bbb C_\infty$ i.e.

> Let $f$ is a function holomorphic on some connected open subset $D\subset\Bbb C_\infty$. If $z_0\in D$ such that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|$ for all $z$ in some nbd of $z_0$ then $f$ is constant on $D$.

Here $\Bbb C_\infty =\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ and assume $f$ is well-defined

Comment: Sure. A non-constant analytic function $X\to \Bbb{C}$ doesn't have any local maximum of $|f|$, this is immediate from the Taylor expansion at a point.

Comment: If $\infty \in D$ this follows by Liouville's Theorem. Otherwise it follows by the usual MMP.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Liouville theorem follows from the maximum modulus principle. If $f$ is entire and bounded then $(f(z)-f(0))/z$ attains its maximum on $\Bbb{C}$ so it is constant.

Comment: @reuns Liouville theorem also follows from Cauchy integral formula (in particular Cauchy's inequality)